# Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream

Tags: java, file, encoding, stream, character-encoding

With reference to the following thread:
[Java App : Unable to read iso-8859-1 encoded file correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498636/java-app-unable-to-read-iso-8859-1-encoded-file-correctly)

What is the best way to programatically determine the correct charset encoding of an inputstream/file ?

I have tried using the following:

```
File in =  new File(args[0]);
InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(in));
System.out.println(r.getEncoding());
```

But on a file which I know to be encoded with ISO8859_1 the above code yields ASCII, which is not correct, and does not allow me to correctly render the content of the file back to the console.

Comment: Eduard is right, "You cannot determine the encoding of a arbitrary byte stream". All other proposals give you ways (and libraries) to do best guessing. But in the end they are still guesses.

Comment: `Reader.getEncoding` returns the encoding the reader was set up to use, which in your case is the default encoding.

Comment: ```System.getProperty("file.encoding")``` it returns string. ex - ```FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);  String encoding = System.getProperty("fis.encoding");```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I have used this library, similar to jchardet for detecting encoding in Java:
https://github.com/albfernandez/juniversalchardet

Comment: I found that this was more accurate: http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/ (I was testing on Western European language documents encoded in ISO 8859-1 , windows-1252, utf-8)

Comment: This juniversalchardet does not work. It delivers UTF-8 most of time, even if the file is 100% windows-1212 encoded.

Comment: It does not detect Eastern European windows-1250

Comment: I tried following code snippet for detection on file from "https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt"    but got null as detected character set.   UniversalDetector ud = new UniversalDetector(null);
   byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(file));
   ud.handleData(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
   ud.dataEnd();
   detectedCharset = ud.getDetectedCharset();

Comment: Juniversalchardet doesn't support  ISO-8859-1, one of the most common charsets.

Answer (score 109):

You cannot determine the encoding of a arbitrary byte stream. This is the nature of encodings. A encoding means a mapping between a byte value and its representation. So every encoding "could" be the right.

The [getEncoding()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#getEncoding%28%29) method will return the encoding which was set up (read the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#getEncoding%28%29)) for the stream. It will not guess the encoding for you.

Some streams tell you which encoding was used to create them: XML, HTML. But not an arbitrary byte stream.

Anyway, you could try to guess an encoding on your own if you have to. Every language has a common frequency for every char. In English the char e appears very often but ê will appear very very seldom. In a ISO-8859-1 stream there are usually no 0x00 chars. But a UTF-16 stream has a lot of them.

Or: you could ask the user. I've already seen applications which present you a snippet of the file in different encodings and ask you to select the "correct" one.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The op should probably be using http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GUESSENC/Home or http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CharsetDetector.html or http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: So how does my editor, notepad++ know how to open the file and show me the right characters ?

Comment: @Hamidam it is by luck that it shows you the right characters. When it guesses wrongly (and it often does), there is an option (Menu >> Encoding) that allows you to change the encoding.

Comment: @Eduard: "So every encoding "could" be the right." not quite right.  Many text encodings have several patterns that are invalid, which are a flag that the text is _probably_ not that encoding.  In fact, given the the first two bytes of a file, only 38% of the combinations are valid UTF8.  The odds of the first 5 codepoints being valid UTF8 by chance is less than .77%.  Likewise, UTF16BE and LE are usually easily identified by the large number of zero bytes and where they are.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to get at least as accurate a method as Notepad++ or just plain Notepad. Can nobody tell us what that is?

Answer (score 40):

check this out:
http://site.icu-project.org/ (icu4j)
 they have libraries for detecting charset from IOStream
could be simple like this:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
CharsetDetector cd = new CharsetDetector();
cd.setText(bis);
CharsetMatch cm = cd.detect();

if (cm != null) {
   reader = cm.getReader();
   charset = cm.getName();
}else {
   throw new UnsupportedCharsetException()
}
```

Comment: i tried but it greatly fails: i made 2 text files in eclipse both containing "öäüß". One set to iso encoding and one to utf8 - both are detected as utf8!
So i tried a file safed somewhere on my hd (windows) - this one was detected correctly ("windows-1252"). Then i created two new file on hd one one edited with editor the other one with notepad++. in both cases "Big5" (Chinese) was detected!

Comment: EDIT: Ok i should check cm.getConfidence() - with my short "äöüß" the confidence is 10. So i have to decide what confidence is good enought - but thats absolutly ok for this endeavour (charset detection)

Comment: Direct link to sample code:  http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection

Comment: The main issue with using ICU4J for character set detection is that the JAR weighs in at 13MB. I've extracted the chardet feature from ICU4J and packaged it into a standalone 75KB library at https://github.com/sigpwned/chardet4j. Same code, smaller footprint.

Answer (score 31):

Here are my favorites:

**[TikaEncodingDetector](http://tika.apache.org/)**

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.any23</groupId>
  <artifactId>apache-any23-encoding</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Sample:

```
public static Charset guessCharset(InputStream is) throws IOException {
  return Charset.forName(new TikaEncodingDetector().guessEncoding(is));    
}
```

**[GuessEncoding](https://github.com/codehaus/guessencoding)**

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.guessencoding</groupId>
  <artifactId>guessencoding</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Sample:

```
  public static Charset guessCharset2(File file) throws IOException {
    return CharsetToolkit.guessEncoding(file, 4096, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  }
```

Comment: *Nota:* **TikaEncodingDetector 1.1** is actually a thin wrapper around **ICU4J 3.4** `CharsetDectector` class.

Comment: Unfortunately both libs do not work. In one case it identifies a UTF-8 file with german Umlaute as ISO-8859-1 and US-ASCII.

Comment: @Brain: Is your tested file actually in an UTF-8 format and does it include a BOM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer the file is a UTF-8 without BOM. I checked it with Notepad++, also by changing the encoding and asserting that the "Umlaute" still are visible.

Answer (score 16):

#### Which library to use?

As of this writing, they are three libraries that emerge:

- [GuessEncoding](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.guessencoding/guessencoding)
- [ICU4j](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu)
- [juniversalchardet](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet)

I don't include [Apache Any23](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.any23/apache-any23-encoding) because it uses ICU4j 3.4 under the hood.

#### How to tell which one has detected the *right* charset (or as close as possible)?

It's impossible to certify the charset detected by each above libraries. However, it's possible to ask them in turn and score the returned response.

#### How to score the returned response?

Each response can be assigned one point. The more points a response have, the more confidence the detected charset has. This is a simple scoring method. You can elaborate others.

#### Is there any sample code?

Here is a full snippet implementing the strategy described in the previous lines.

```
public static String guessEncoding(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    // Load input data
    long count = 0;
    int n = 0, EOF = -1;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    while ((EOF != (n = input.read(buffer))) && (count <= Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        count += n;
    }
    
    if (count > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Inputstream too large.");
    }

    byte[] data = output.toByteArray();

    // Detect encoding
    Map<String, int[]> encodingsScores = new HashMap<>();

    // * GuessEncoding
    updateEncodingsScores(encodingsScores, new CharsetToolkit(data).guessEncoding().displayName());

    // * ICU4j
    CharsetDetector charsetDetector = new CharsetDetector();
    charsetDetector.setText(data);
    charsetDetector.enableInputFilter(true);
    CharsetMatch cm = charsetDetector.detect();
    if (cm != null) {
        updateEncodingsScores(encodingsScores, cm.getName());
    }

    // * juniversalchardset
    UniversalDetector universalDetector = new UniversalDetector(null);
    universalDetector.handleData(data, 0, data.length);
    universalDetector.dataEnd();
    String encodingName = universalDetector.getDetectedCharset();
    if (encodingName != null) {
        updateEncodingsScores(encodingsScores, encodingName);
    }

    // Find winning encoding
    Map.Entry<String, int[]> maxEntry = null;
    for (Map.Entry<String, int[]> e : encodingsScores.entrySet()) {
        if (maxEntry == null || (e.getValue()[0] > maxEntry.getValue()[0])) {
            maxEntry = e;
        }
    }

    String winningEncoding = maxEntry.getKey();
    //dumpEncodingsScores(encodingsScores);
    return winningEncoding;
}

private static void updateEncodingsScores(Map<String, int[]> encodingsScores, String encoding) {
    String encodingName = encoding.toLowerCase();
    int[] encodingScore = encodingsScores.get(encodingName);

    if (encodingScore == null) {
        encodingsScores.put(encodingName, new int[] { 1 });
    } else {
        encodingScore[0]++;
    }
}    

private static void dumpEncodingsScores(Map<String, int[]> encodingsScores) {
    System.out.println(toString(encodingsScores));
}

private static String toString(Map<String, int[]> encodingsScores) {
    String GLUE = ", ";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Map.Entry<String, int[]> e : encodingsScores.entrySet()) {
        sb.append(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue()[0] + GLUE);
    }
    int len = sb.length();
    sb.delete(len - GLUE.length(), len);

    return "{ " + sb.toString() + " }";
}
```

*Improvements:*
The `guessEncoding` method reads the inputstream entirely. For large inputstreams this can be a concern. All these libraries would read the whole inputstream. This would imply a large time consumption for detecting the charset.

It's possible to limit the initial data loading to a few bytes and perform the charset detection on those few bytes only.

Answer (score 14):

You can certainly *validate* the file for a particular charset by [decoding](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#decode(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20java.nio.CharBuffer,%20boolean)) it with a [`CharsetDecoder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) and watching out for "malformed-input" or "unmappable-character" errors. Of course, this only tells you if a charset is wrong; it doesn't tell you if it is correct. For that, you need a basis of comparison to evaluate the decoded results, e.g. do you know beforehand if the characters are restricted to some subset, or whether the text adheres to some strict format? The bottom line is that charset detection is guesswork without any guarantees.

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know, there is no general library in this context to be suitable for all types of problems. So, for each problem you should test the existing libraries and select the best one which satisfies your problem’s constraints, but often none of them is appropriate. In these cases you can write your own Encoding Detector! As I have wrote ...

I’ve wrote a meta java tool for detecting charset encoding of HTML Web pages, using IBM ICU4j and Mozilla JCharDet as the built-in components. [Here](https://github.com/shabanali-faghani/IUST-HTMLCharDet) you can find my tool, please read the README section before anything else. Also, you can find some basic concepts of this problem in my [paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-28940-3_17) and in its references.

Bellow I provided some helpful comments which I’ve experienced in my work:

- Charset detection is not a foolproof process, because it is essentially based on statistical data and what actually happens is **guessing** not **detecting**
- icu4j is the main tool in this context by IBM, imho
- Both TikaEncodingDetector and Lucene-ICU4j are using icu4j and their accuracy had not a meaningful difference from which the icu4j in my tests (at most %1, as I remember)
- icu4j is much more general than jchardet, icu4j is just a bit biased to IBM family encodings while jchardet is strongly biased to utf-8
- Due to the widespread use of UTF-8 in HTML-world; jchardet is a better choice than icu4j in overall, but is not the best choice!
- icu4j is great for East Asian specific encodings like EUC-KR, EUC-JP, SHIFT_JIS, BIG5 and the GB family encodings
- Both icu4j and jchardet are debacle in dealing with HTML pages with Windows-1251 and Windows-1256 encodings. Windows-1251 aka cp1251 is widely used for Cyrillic-based languages like Russian and Windows-1256 aka cp1256 is widely used for Arabic
- Almost all encoding detection tools are using statistical methods, so the accuracy of output strongly depends on the size and the contents of the input
- Some encodings are essentially the same just with a partial differences, so in some cases the guessed or detected encoding may be false but at the same time be true! As about Windows-1252 and ISO-8859-1. (refer to the last paragraph under the 5.2 section of my paper)

Comment: The question is cluttered with really bad and duplicative answers. Thank you for the best answer by far.

Comment: @DouglasHeld Glad it helped. This thread is a good example of [matthew effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_effect) in stackoverflow!

Answer (score 6):

The libs above are simple BOM detectors which of course only work if there is a BOM in the beginning of the file.  Take a look at http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/ which does scans the text

Comment: just at tip, but there is no "above" on this site - consider stating the libraries you are referring to.

Answer (score 5):

If you use ICU4J (http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/)

Here is my code:

```java
String charset = "ISO-8859-1"; //Default chartset, put whatever you want

byte[] fileContent = null;
FileInputStream fin = null;

//create FileInputStream object
fin = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());

/*
 * Create byte array large enough to hold the content of the file.
 * Use File.length to determine size of the file in bytes.
 */
fileContent = new byte[(int) file.length()];

/*
 * To read content of the file in byte array, use
 * int read(byte[] byteArray) method of java FileInputStream class.
 *
 */
fin.read(fileContent);

byte[] data =  fileContent;

CharsetDetector detector = new CharsetDetector();
detector.setText(data);

CharsetMatch cm = detector.detect();

if (cm != null) {
    int confidence = cm.getConfidence();
    System.out.println("Encoding: " + cm.getName() + " - Confidence: " + confidence + "%");
    //Here you have the encode name and the confidence
    //In my case if the confidence is > 50 I return the encode, else I return the default value
    if (confidence > 50) {
        charset = cm.getName();
    }
}
```

Remember to put all the try-catch need it.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: IMO, this answer is perfectible. If you want to use ICU4j, try this one instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4013565/363573.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the encoding of your data, it is not so easy to determine, but you could try to use a [library to guess it](http://glaforge.free.fr/wiki/index.php?wiki=GuessEncoding). Also, there is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457655/java-charset-and-windows/457849#457849).

Answer (score 4):

I found a nice third party library which can detect actual encoding:
http://glaforge.free.fr/wiki/index.php?wiki=GuessEncoding

I didn't test it extensively but it seems to work.

Comment: The Link to the "GuessEncoding" project website is: https://xircles.codehaus.org/p/guessencoding

Answer (score 1):

For ISO8859_1 files, there is not an easy way to distinguish them from ASCII.  For Unicode files however one can generally detect this based on the first few bytes of the file.

UTF-8 and UTF-16 files include a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) (BOM) at the very beginning of the file.  The BOM is a zero-width non-breaking space.

Unfortunately, for historical reasons, Java does not detect this automatically.  Programs like Notepad will check the BOM and use the appropriate encoding.  Using unix or Cygwin, you can check the BOM with the file command.  For example:

```
$ file sample2.sql 
sample2.sql: Unicode text, UTF-16, big-endian
```

For Java, I suggest you check out this code, which will detect the common file formats and select the correct encoding:  [How to read a file and automatically specify the correct encoding](http://www.ericbt.com/Blog/60)

Comment: Not all UTF-8 or UTF-16 files have a BOM, as it is not required, and UTF-8 BOM is discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to TikaEncodingDetector is to use [Tika AutoDetectReader](https://tika.apache.org/1.2/api/org/apache/tika/detect/AutoDetectReader.html).

```
Charset charset = new AutoDetectReader(new FileInputStream(file)).getCharset();
```

Comment: Tike AutoDetectReader uses EncodingDetector loaded with ServiceLoader. Which EncodingDetector implementations do you use?

Answer (score 0):

A good strategy to handle this, is with a way to auto detect the input charset.

I use org.xml.sax.InputSource in Java 11 to solve it:

```
...    
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
...

InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(inputStream);
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
    inputSource.getByteStream(), inputSource.getEncoding()
  );
```

Input sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<rss xmlns:dc="https://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
<channel>
...**strong text**
```

Comment: As xml declares the encoding to use then InputSource isn't really auto-detecting the char encoding here. This code does not help for a general stream (eg from csv etc)

Answer (score -1):

In plain Java:

```
final String[] encodings = { "US-ASCII", "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", "UTF-16BE", "UTF-16LE", "UTF-16" };

List<String> lines;

for (String encoding : encodings) {
    try {
        lines = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.forName(encoding));
        for (String line : lines) {
            // do something...
        }
        break;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(encoding + " failed, trying next.");
    }
}
```

This approach will try the encodings one by one until one works or we run out of them.
(BTW my encodings list has only those items because they are the charsets implementations required on every Java platform, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)

Comment: But ISO-8859-1 (among many others that you haven't listed) will always succeed. And, of course, this is just guessing, which can't recover the lost metadata that is essential to text file communication.

Comment: Hi @TomBlodget, are you suggesting that the encodings order should be different?

Comment: I saying that many will "work" but only one is "right". And you don't need to test for ISO-8859-1 because it will always "work".

Answer (score -12):

Can you pick the appropriate char set in the [Constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html):

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(in), "ISO8859_1");
```

Comment: The point here was to see whether the charset could be determined programatically.

Comment: No, it won't guess it for you.  You have to supply it.

Comment: There may be a heuristic method, as suggested by some of the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457655/java-charset-and-windows/457849#457849