# java bufferedReader, writes something different than it reads

Tags: java, bufferedreader, cal, navision, bufferedwriter

i parsed a text (CAL code) with BufferedReader and BufferedWriter in Java, unfortunately, lines which i red and wrote with outStream.write(line); have changed, please look at Screenshots:

http://uploadz.eu/images/4qz8mtkm2d9zx3x5ms3n.png
h**p://uploadz.eu/images/c03hgkrgrmit2ij2mug.png

as you see, some special character did changed the lines although i intended NOT to change them.

as far as i know, Bufferedwriter / Reader should work in unicode by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `BufferedWriter` and `BufferedReader` are encoding agnostic - they never deal with the actual encodings, as they're just buffering existing readers and writers.

Now `FileWriter` and `FileReader` use the default system encoding (urgh). To work round this, you should usually use an `InputStream` / `InputStreamReader` or `OutputStream` / `OutputStreamWriter` pair (possibly wrapped in a `BufferedReader` / `BufferedWriter`), and specify the encoding explicitly.

You haven't said what you're actually reading from - is it a file? Do you know the encoding of the file?

Comment: BufferedWriter df = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter("out.txt"));

does not work.

it is a .txt file.  unfortunately I don't know the encoding of the file.

Comment: i found out: it should be ANSI. i'd appreciate further suggestions.

Comment: "ANSI" isn't one single encoding. It can mean a variety of different encodings, usually 8 bit extensions to ASCII.

Comment: @dayscott: you can't just specify the filename for OutputStreamWriter. The constructor for OutputStreamWriter takes an OutputStream as its parameter. So replace "out.txt" with: new FileOutputStream("out.txt"). You might also find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010 to be useful

Answer (score 0):

You should either know the encoding if you're going to treat the content as text (String), or, when copying is your goal, or treat the content as a byte array.

Comment: firefox: http://uploadz.eu/images/7anvv8hok4bdt2ewylt1.jpg

java compiler: "Cp1252"

i googled that "Cp1252" seems to be the java "standard" charset.

Comment: wordStream = new FileInputStream( "x.txt" );
  InputStreamReader input = null;
  input = new java.io.InputStreamReader( wordStream, "Cp1252"  ); 
  reader  = new BufferedReader(input);
    String str;
    try {
   while((str = reader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(str);
   }

unfortunately the output is still wrong encoded.

Comment: Problem solved ! 

simply by using the RandomAccessFile class. I used readLine and writeBytes. As a separator I used System.getProperty("line.separator")  - running Win XP. 

thx for the support guys :)