# What is XML BOM and how do I detect it?

Tags: java, xml

What exactly is the BOM in a ANSI XML document and should it be removed?   Should a XML document be in UTF-8 instead?  Can anyone tell me a Java method that will detect the BOM?    The BOM consists of the characters EF BB BF .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For a ANSI XML file it should actually be removed. If you want to use UTF-8 you don't really need it. Only for UTF-16 and UTF-32 it is needed.

> The Byte-Order-Mark (or BOM), is a
> special marker added at the very
> beginning of an Unicode file encoded
> in UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32. It is used
> to indicate whether the file uses the
> big-endian or little-endian byte
> order. The BOM is mandatory for UTF-16
> and UTF-32, but it is optional for
> UTF-8.

*(Source: https://www.opentag.com/xfaq_enc.htm#enc_bom)*

Regarding the question on how detect this in java.

Check the following answer to this question: Java : [How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream/499033#499033) and if you now want to determine the BOM yourself (at your own risk) check for example this code  [Java Tip: How to read a file and automatically specify the correct encoding](https://ericbt.com/Blog/60).

Basically just read in the first few bytes yourself and then determine if you **may** have found a BOM.

Comment: thanks for the great answer.  since i am expecting the file to be UTF-8 I am just ignoring the first 3 chars using something like:  String file1sub = getXMLContents(file1).substring(3);

Comment: @jitter - I'm not sure where your quote on BOMs comes from. XML doesn't require a BOM in UTF-16 or UTF-32 documents - a parser should manage without. XML encoding detection: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-guessing Otherwise, the requirement for a BOM it is domain-dependent. Unicode.org BOM FAQ: http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM

Comment: that explains why Notepad++ allows you to set the default for new files to be "UTF-8 without BOM"

Answer (score 20):

The byte order mark is likely to be one of these byte sequences:

```
     UTF-8 BOM: ef bb bf 
  UTF-16BE BOM: fe ff 
  UTF-16LE BOM: ff fe 
  UTF-32BE BOM: 00 00 fe ff 
  UTF-32LE BOM: ff fe 00 00
```

These are the variously encoded forms of the Unicode codepoint U+FEFF. This can be expressed as a Java char literal using `'\uFEFF'` (Java char values are *implicitly* UTF-16). Since U+FEFF isn't in most encodings, it is not possible for this BOM codepoint to be encoded by them. ([More on encoding the BOM using Java here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_boms).)

When it comes to BOMs and XML, they are optional (see also the [Unicode BOM FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM)). Detection of encoding in XML is relatively straightforward if the encoding is specified in the declaration. Always make sure that the XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`) matches the encoding used to write the document. If you are strict about this, parsers should be able to interpret your documents correctly.  ([XML spec on encoding detection.](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-guessing))

I advocate encoding as Unicode wherever possible (see also the [10 Commandments of Unicode](http://cafe.elharo.com/programming/the-ten-commandments-of-unicode/)). That said, XML allows the representation of any Unicode character via escape entities (e.g. 'A' could be represented by `&#x0041;`), so it isn't necessarily a requirement to avoid data loss.

Comment: *»XML allows the representation of any Unicode character via escape entities«* – well, except you need CDATA sections ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Do not insert a BOM in a utf-8 file: if two such files are merged, you end up with a BOM in the middle which might break an applicaton, or cause an xml parser to throw an exception.

Comment: Ahh.  Interesting tip.  I never thought of that.  Luckily, merging XML files is not that common.

Comment: And what about BOMs in an UTF-16LE file?

Comment: You should never merge XML files as simple text files. Every XML file should start with a prolog.

Answer (score 4):

OP:

> Can anyone tell me a Java method that will detect the BOM?

`org.apache.commons.io.input.BOMInputStream` Javadocs:

> This class detects these bytes and, if required, can automatically skip them and return the subsequent byte as the first byte in the stream.

Comment: I'm not sure how this might be helpful to answering the question "What is XML BOM and how do I detect it?"

Comment: @Matt - I copied the description from the Javadocs. Hope that helps.