# How to manage unicode inputs in terminal unix in C89

Tags: c, input, unicode, utf-8

I made some research on this subject (unicode inputs in c89) but i didn't find everythings i wanted to know.

Someone can explain me how he manage the whole keyboard (utf8) with some basic operation (only looking at the binary value), because i didn't find how make the difference between character keys and function keys.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195262/how-to-read-an-utf-8-encoded-file-containing-chinese-characters-and-output-them may help you or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113270/how-to-read-unicode-utf-8-binary-file-line-by-line

Comment: The C89 standard predates UTF-8 so there's no specific support in the standard for UTF-8. Also Unicode doesn't define code points for function keys so there's no standard representation of function keys in UTF-8. You'll need to figure out the particular encoding for function keys that your terminal uses.

Comment: my terminal use utf8, that's why i just need to know how find unicode binary value of Ctrl, Alt.... Because i see too many things on the internet

Answer (score 0):

That's not unicode, but likely [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence). VT100/52 etc. for 80ies devices (Atari-ST used VT52 for instance).