# Illegal characters in path parsing token xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

```
var a = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlToken))
```

This throws : Illegal characters in path Exception.

I tried the following but nothing

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlToken);
```

If you think that my xml has 2 roots I made this step I after the above line get None

```
var a = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml))
```

The value of xmlToken is:

```
<xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" /><KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /></e:EncryptionMethod><KeyInfo><o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><X509Data><X509IssuerSerial><X509IssuerName>CN=BDDC1CA00, DC=HRT, DC=local</X509IssuerName><X509SerialNumber>120366057797367722148390</X509SerialNumber></X509IssuerSerial></X509Data></o:SecurityTokenReference></KeyInfo><e:CipherData><e:CipherValue>PSAA8Gzcu+MIKB4T3RttHJhDS+TP3VgHP85BVrDua4DkNDtOL1ZNBaEknPz74rBbe/Pt1VaCw+K0JFw/xV0i7qCJrQ1yhYbUzjjOODnCZig4td1QI2h4RChSzrsXJ9ny9wjPAvrOIrXMWMZfiiFUFAkQbGaiJrBfLDj8UTMPxzxJfokINHk7KxAtTqRZkWRpyAlatM768juXD78hje7gucwMZsfeD6Q6EI+eW/tBOV0AzA3woYuwvCbvmYEv7Pz0cCZrvnJ5I5w8HfA7Smi+P53xNPzDzv+5q3SfM75fxP23obCRLTty9CTw7I5Xjhaq2uZkARFaMXztVBctiyRCbg==</e:CipherValue></e:CipherData></e:EncryptedKey></KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData>
```

and formated looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
   <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
   <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
         <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
         </e:EncryptionMethod>
         <KeyInfo>
            <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
               <X509Data>
                  <X509IssuerSerial>
                     <X509IssuerName>CN=BDDC1CA00, DC=HRT, DC=local</X509IssuerName>
                     <X509SerialNumber>120366057797367722148390</X509SerialNumber>
                  </X509IssuerSerial>
               </X509Data>
            </o:SecurityTokenReference>
         </KeyInfo>
         <e:CipherData>
            <e:CipherValue>NI/FjtC6xeFpssGl8hNtsBTWja6wfJIzhY9c0YkPL3N0d4QVLbvBmF3BAfwfUMKtR2ZgX5x60jbIZkfuL13T1AlT8/Mze3gsN5P505VawwrjJ/RyrjtTm1XJ/AbfFF6sJS+ATHLoRoRE0roUArf30rzcXiyyxsgZwvd5jBALJgZNlx+i/7g3niq+Xwh7zAdZ5dQsaxnROT8BcyYS2bs1fn7kFXkXqJJeGlYR7FWUeu0ndWWJZcJbYQWMJfI4sfZ8dtUkQY6Z/v8ba2DTIEF5COXftt3tC1ygn8ZuTe82t/aZCmmf5pAtDKMBjuRct/mBUrJb0bOVx02mGiTy07FN+Q==</e:CipherValue>
         </e:CipherData>
      </e:EncryptedKey>
   </KeyInfo>
   <xenc:CipherData>
      <xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue>
   </xenc:CipherData>
</xenc:EncryptedData>
```

Comment: Both work for me.  Can you post your entire code?  Especially where you declare/get your xml string.

Comment: Only minor anomalies i'm seeing is some whitespace in the e:CipherData elements before the <e:CipherValue> opening tag. Other than that loading those both work for me as well.

Comment: the values comes from a POST operation via web

Comment: well, without providing us with the exact string you're trying to parse, we can't reproduce your error.

Comment: The string you can see it below "The value of xmlToken is:"

Comment: Are you *sure* that you're calling the right overload of `XmlTextReader`? Because this error is usually thrown by overload that accepts filepath (string) to XML file that contains XML when it tries to interpret XML as filepath. I reconstructed the example from your code and data and there was no error, it's a valid XML.

Comment: @IvanG I am using this one new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlToken))  StringReader inherits from TeaxtReader

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have run into similar issues where the cause was a BOM character.

Ref [What is XML BOM and how do I detect it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772321/what-is-xml-bom-and-how-do-i-detect-it)