# Using UTF-8 identifier

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8

I get an String Stream form HTTP Request. The Stream looks like:

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

The first three tokens means that the String is encoded to UTF-8.

I'm making Files with the String. While reading them i get an error:

With this method i'm making Files with that String:

```
private void writeToFile(String data, String fileName) {
    try {
        String UTF8 = "UTF-8";
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

        String xmlCut = data.substring(3);

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/example/Test");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir,fileName);

        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream,UTF8),BUFFER_SIZE);
        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        f.write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        f.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("writeToFile: ", "Datei-Erstellung fehlgeschlagen: " + e.toString());
    }

}
```

As you can see, I've added the substring method to cut the first three tokens because this leads to a crash. The Problem is that then the Files are coded in ASCI.

Method to read files:

```
 private String readFromFile(String fileName) {
    String ret = "";
    String UTF8 = "UTF-8";
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(fileName);

        if (inputStream != null) {


            BufferedReader bufferedReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,UTF8),BUFFER_SIZE);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader1.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("readFromFile: ", "Datei nicht gefunden: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("readFromFile: ", "Kann Datei nicht lesen: " + e.toString());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If i don't cut the UTF-8 tokens then i get this error from stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.w3c.dom.NodeList org.w3c.dom.Document.getElementsByTagName(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at de.example.app.ListViewActivity.setListProjectData(ListViewActivity.java:226)
```

It's here:

```
public void setListProjectData(String filename) {

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xmlData = readFromFile(filename);
    String xmlCut = xmlData.substring(3);
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(filename);

    NodeList nodeListProject = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_PROJECT);


    for (int i = 0; i < nodeListProject.getLength(); i++) {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nodeListProject.item(i);

        map.put(KEY_UUID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_UUID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_JOBTITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_JOBTITLE));
        map.put(KEY_JOBINFO, parser.getValue(e, KEY_JOBINFO));
        map.put(KEY_PROJECTIMAGE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PROJECTIMAGE));


        projectItems.add(map);
    }
}
```

I get the data from HTTP by here:

```
public String getXMLFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        try {
            //defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            /*
            final InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8");
            InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
            is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
```

*/
                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

```
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return xml;
```

So, how can i encode them to UTF-8? Am I doing it right?

Comment: It's **ANSI**, not **ANSII**. You are mixing `ANSI` and `ASCII`.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Can you post the stacktrace from LogCat?

Comment: I guess you should check if the file begins with a **BOM** or not. If so, cut it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772321/what-is-xml-bom-and-how-do-i-detect-it

Comment: If i cut the tokens, then the file is coded in ANSI

Comment: You have to save it as Unicode UTF-8, `without BOM`.

Comment: It's **ASCII**, not **ASCI**. You are now mixing `ASCII` with `ANSI`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not in the code you have posted but in code that gets data from HTTP request.

You are passing `String data` to `writeToFile` method. String in Java is `UTF-16` encoded. If you have `UTF-8` encoded data in that string, then no amount of further encoding-decoding is going to fix that data that is already broken.

You should use `xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8)` to decode data properly.

There is additional issue if returned data contains `UTF-8 BOM`. Above line will correctly decode data, but it will leave superfluous (and wrong) `BOM` in place.

To solve that either server has to return data without `BOM`, or `BOM` has to be stripped down. To do so following code (or similar can be used)

```
public static String stripBOM(InputStream stream)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        byte[] bom = new byte[3];
        stream.read(bom);
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        os.close();
        return os.toString("UTF-8");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

So `xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8)` can be replaced with

```
 InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
 xml = stripBOM(is);
```