# Character corruption going from BufferedReader to BufferedWriter in java

Tags: java, html-parsing, special-characters, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

In Java, I am trying to parse an HTML file that contains complex text such as greek symbols.

I encounter a known problem when text contains a left facing quotation mark. Text such as

```
mutations to particular “hotspot” regions
```

becomes

```
 mutations to particular “hotspot�? regions
```

I have isolated the problem by writting a simple text copy meathod:

```
public static int CopyFile()
{
    try
    {
    StringBuffer sb = null;
    String NullSpace = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
    String line;
    BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
while((line = input.readLine())!=null)
    {
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        //Parsing would happen
        sb.append(line);
        output.write(sb.toString()+NullSpace);
    }
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Can anybody offer some advice as how to correct this problem?

★My solution

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in,"utf-8");
        Reader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
        Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
        int r;
        while ((r = reader.read()) != -1)
        {
            if (r<126)
            {
                output.write(r);
            }
            else
            {
                output.write("&#"+Integer.toString(r)+";");
            }
        }
        output.flush();
```

Comment: is it just me or is the "buffer" Reader obsolete in the last snippet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file read is not in the same encoding (probably UTF-8) as the file written (probably ISO-8859-1).

Try the following to generate a file with UTF-8 encoding:

```
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile),"UTF8"));
```

Unfortunately, determining the encoding of a file is very difficult. See [Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream)

Comment: And as far as I know there isn't really an automated way to obtain the encoding of a text file.

Comment: "UTF8" and 16 don't seem to work even though <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> is explicitely stated in the HTML...

Does anybdoy know how to look up encoding by going from a know character in a file to an encoding?

Comment: I tried 
US-ASCII 
ISO-8859-1
UTF-8
UTF-16BE
UTF-16LE  
UTF-16
And they don't work...

Comment: The character's decimal value is "8221", it should be Unicode right?

Comment: Problem was solved by changing to UTF-8 
AND parsing the entire file and replacing all special above 126 characters to "&#xxx" format.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Thierry-Dimitri Roy wrote, if you know the encoding you have to create your [FileReader](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) with a bit of extra work. From the docs:

> Convenience class for reading
>   character files. The constructors of
>   this class assume that the default
>   character encoding and the default
>   byte-buffer size are appropriate. To
>   specify these values yourself,
>   construct an InputStreamReader on a
>   FileInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadoc for `FileReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) says:

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate.  To specify these values yourself, construct an InputStreamReader on a FileInputStream.

In your case the default character encoding is probably **not** appropriate. Find what encoding the input file uses, and specify it. For example:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "charset name goes here");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(isr);
```