# Multibyte encoding in java

Tags: encoding, multibyte, cjk

i have no idea of how to add multibyte encoding support  and very little knowledge on multibyte languages.
Being working on a search engine, my application scans code in all programming languages.
Some sourcecode might have CJK encoding in their comments section.
For easiness sake, i take java as source-code sample and my application is also in java.

First thing,  i want to write test cases to see if to-be-indexed source-code has CJK encoding and if it is encoded by my application.
I want my tests to fail if support not included so that can be added in future.

But i have no idea how to test it ,
how to entre CJK in input samples for unit test and what would be output in Java application console.

Comment: You'd typically want to know what encodings you'll be dealing with in advance as I don't know that there's a straightforward means (if at all) of determining the encoding of a particular file.  UTF8 / Unicode are the way to go if you've a choice of input encoding, otherwise you might have to muddle through with user-selectable encodings.

Comment: All Unicode encodings are multibyte, aren’t they?  Anyway, it is not possible to *detect* which encoding you have. You *must* be told in which encoding the data should be treated.

Comment: It’s not quite clear what you’re asking here. Do you want help with reading files in a specific character encoding, with determining the character encoding of a file, with creating a file using a specific character encoding in order to test your work, or with some combination of those things?

Answer (score 0):

The presence of a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) might be of use, but they are optional. There are other methods for determining the encoding when UTF is used. This may be of use: [Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream).