# BufferedReader automatic encoding type

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader

I am using BufferedReader to get data fro ma url.

```
 URL url = new URL("http://");
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "windows-1251"));
```

On some url's encoding is **windows-1251** (cyrilyc) so i specified that in the reader. But on some ones, enconding is different, e.g **KOI8-R** Any way to get the data from both sources without using naother reader? I really can use only one here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the BufferedReader cannot examine the Content-Enconding header. You have to supply that. Or use a library for encoding recognition/detection.

Comment: If you need general enconding recognition, try [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/). In the case you need something more HTTP/HTML specific, try the [Jericho HTML Parser]/http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) with it's [`Source`](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/Source.html#Source(java.net.URLConnection)) class.

Also make sure that your JVM supports your encodings.