# How do I detect if a text file is encoded using Windows-1256?

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

I would really like to get if the file is  Windows-1256 or not. Is there a way to recognize if text file is Windows-1256 in Java?

Comment: Usually you can only detect which encodings text is not, by bytes which are not valid in a given encoding. e.g. a block of plain ASCII text could be any number of encodings originally (though it shouldn't matter which one it was)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this API to check the encoding:

http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/

And have a look at this question:

[Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream)

Comment: -1 jchardet can't distinguish between most of the cp12xx encodings. Only 1250, 1251 and 1253 are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Add an encoding header to the file. Many text editors do this:

```
# -*- coding: cp1256 -*-
```

Other than that, there is no reliable way to do this.

The problem is that the cp12xx encodings aren't very different from each other. They *look* different on the screen but in the data of the files, there is nothing which says `0x8a` means  arabic `ٹ` (1256) or Š (1250 and 1252) or nothing (1255).

PS: the last sentence looks wrong because of right-to-left issues. The code "(1256)" is actually after the arabic character.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the choice of Windows-1256 (Arabic), UTF-8 and Windows-1252 (part of Western Europe). Then you can register proofs of wrong encoding for say UTF-8 (unsensible sequence) and Windows-1252. Some sequences of Windows-1252 would throw an unparsable exception for UTF-8 anyway-

```
try {
    readInUTF8(file);
} catch (IsWindows1256Exception e {
    readInWindow1256(file);
}
```

*(Pseudo-code)*