# Is there way to check charset encoding of .txt file with Java?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, file-encodings

Is there way to check is text file (.txt) encoded with Unicode or UTF-8 with Java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot know with absolute certainty which charset is used in the general case. I found this to be a good read.

http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html

Especially the section **Automatic detection of encoding**.

Answer (score 2):

Uhm, theoretically, how would you know if it is unicode?

This is the real question.
Truthfully, you cannot know, but you can make a decent guess.

See:
[Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream) for more details. :)