# reading text files of different encodings in java

Tags: java, character-encoding

If I had a file encoded in ISO but wanted to read the file as UTF-8 using java would I still get the same text?

would special characters such as µÃÿ display the same?

Answer (score 1):

No, you would not. UTF-8 does not encode characters beyond U+007f in the same way as ISO-8859-1 (ISO-8859-1 encodes U+0080 through U+00ff as single bytes `\x80` to `\xff`, while UTF-8 uses two bytes for each of those characters).

You have to use an explicit encoding specification when opening the file: `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(...), <encoding>)`

Comment: On the Internet, just saying "ISO encoding" suggests ISO Latin 1 encoding, since that's the older (more popular) encoding. OP should clarify, to be sure.

Comment: Can you back that up? Why and where is it the most popular?

Comment: Google search. Googling 'ISO encoding' results in no mention of 10646 on the first page at all. Same with "ISO encoding".

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. The way the characters are represented (bitwise) in ISO is not the same as how characters are represented in UTF-8.

However, you can convert a file from ISO to UTF-8, but not UTF-8 to ISO, because there are many more recognizable characters in UTF-8 than there are in ISO.

My recommendation would be to detect the encoding (see: [Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream)) and then to handle each case accordingly.

Comment: If you can at all avoid using a character detection library, though, then you should. Character detection isn't 100%, and can lead to various weird issues when it gets the answer wrong.