# read tags from mp3 file

Tags: java, string, mp3

I have a code that reads the mp3 tag, it's the last 128 bytes of the file

```
try{
    final int TAG_LONG = 128;
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
    byte[] bytesSong = new byte[128];
    byte[] byteTitleArry = new byte[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        byteTitleArry[i] = arrayTag[3+ i];
    }
    String title = new String(byteTitleArry);
}
```

this code works just fine when the title tag (or enything else) is written english chars, but when the tag is a value in non-english chars i get the wrong value, so i used:

```
String title = new String(byteTitleArry, "ISO-8859-8");
```

but this is not generic enough, is there a way to find out what is the tag unicode?

Comment: This seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream

Comment: I think you miss understood me, what I am trying to ask, is if the mp3 file structure holds information about how the tag is being encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an ID3 library instead, e.g. [JAudioTagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/).

Comment: It might be useful, but I am developing an application and I am planning to sell it on Play store therefore I am preferring to write my own code

Comment: JAudioTagger is LGPL, so you can include it in your application and still sell it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ID3v1 you are trying to use does not hold any i18n information. ID3v2 however does. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3