# how to detect encoding of text file before inputStream in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream)

i'm trying to read an ANSI text file in java but, i don't know the encoding of the text inside , is there any way to detect the encoding of text file before getting it using FileInputStream ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to know the encoding of a text file before actually reading it. You have to read a couple of bytes before trying to determine it's encoding.

The tool mentioned in the comments asks you to do exactly that (actually it says *several thousands bytes*) before detecting the encoding of a file.