# Read special symbols from file

Tags: java, file, io

I am trying to read file using Java and the file also containing special characters also.
I am trying to write the contents of file into another file.

What is the solution to read special character files?

Comment: what do you mean with special character?

Comment: what's the encoding of the file?

Comment: special characters like ― and “ and file is using UTF8 encoding style

Answer (score 3):

Encode file in UTF-8 and use java encoding aware streams operators:

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8")
```

Comment: What if the file doesn't have UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: An other "frequent" encoding would be Windows Latin-1, "Windows-1252"

Comment: @Joop Eggen then follow this tread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream

Comment: i am using the code FileReader fr= new FileReader(new File("path of the file")); BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);                     then where to pass the encoding standard.

Comment: Look at the answer @Sumit Singh posted to you

Comment: @user1868052 read javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html use InputStreamReader instead of FileReader