# read special characters from a file and write in another file using java

Tags: java, file, input, io, output

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read special symbols from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875794/read-special-symbols-from-file)

I am trying to copy a file to another file . The file is using encoding standard UTF8 
and file also containing special characters . the program is not able to copy the special characters in another file in the same format the file is being disturbed with box shapes for 
special symbols.

```
 try 
  {
   BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("path of the file")),"UTF8") ;
  BufferedWriter bw= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamReader(new FileOutputStream(new File("path of the output file");
    while(br.readLine()!=null)
   {
     //code here to read and write from a file to another.


    }

   }
  catch(Exception ex  
 { 
 ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: Mmmm... did you try set encoding also and for **OutputStreamWriter**?

Comment: there are many closing parenthesis missing here. To write a read line, you have to know what it is, you are loosing what `br.readLine()` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(new File("path of the output file")),
            "UTF-8"));
```

Or in java 7 use `Files.copy`.

Comment: given UTF8 in FileOutputStream constructor but still the same result

Comment: In the OutputStreamWriter I suppose. Try using [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) or so, to inspect the original file.

Comment: @JoopEggen How to set encoding in Files.copy?

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince as just a file must be copied as-is, there is no need for an encoding with Files.copy. Only if the file was read into java String variables and then written one needs to indicate the encoding of the files, as java keeps all text as Unicode internally. If you have a use-case where you need to convert the encoding: instead of Files.copy use the solution above, or use `Files.readAllLines/write` with charset.