# Mozilla Rhino Character Encoding

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, rhino

Can somebody describe how to specify character encodings properly in JavaScript Rhino for me please?

I am reasonably familiar with sorting out encoding issues between a Java application and the database (MySQL), and between the application and the browser, but this issue seems to involve shell and file i/o.

I have an application written mainly in JavaScript that runs on Rhino, either inside Apache Tomcat or stand-alone via the Rhino shell.

All the js source code is saved as UTF-8 (inside Eclipse), and is loaded into Rhino either using Rhino shell's "load" function, or (if running inside Tomcat) by the following:

```
public static void loadScript( String sFile ) throws Exception {
    java.io.BufferedReader oReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(
        new java.io.InputStreamReader( new java.io.FileInputStream( sDir + sFile ), "UTF-8" ) );
    org.mozilla.javascript.Context cx = contextFactory.enterContext();
    try {
        cx.evaluateReader( scope, oReader, sFile, 1, null );
    } finally {
        org.mozilla.javascript.Context.exit();
    }
    oReader.close();
}
```

Characters such as '£' and '€' specified in the source code are corrupted when output from the application.

Any help gratefully received...

Comment: How are you producing output?  Are you using the `print` function that is bound in the Rhino REPL?  How are symbols corrupted?  Are they written out as if encoded using the JVM's default encoding?

Comment: If this is a Windows OS they are likely being corrupted by System.out

Answer (score 0):

That is not a question of Rhino. The source file have to be read properly with 'UTF-8' encoding support.

You may consider to look at related topic here: [Reading any text file having strange encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511703/java-how-to-read-any-text-file-having-strange-encoding)