# Reading Java byte's as CharSet

Tags: java, character-encoding

Will the particular `CharSet` affect the binary (or integer) value associated with each byte?

Example:

```
String original = foo(); // makes string

byte[] utf8Bytes = original.getBytes("UTF8"); // CharSet is UTF8
byte[] defaultBytes = original.getBytes(); // default CharSet
```

Will `utf8Bytes[1]` always equal `defaultBytes[1]` from a binary/integer point of value?

Comment: It's good practice to *always* specify the charset. And if for some reason you really want the default charset, use Charset.defaultCharset() to make your intention clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will affect the values, and UTF-8 is not the default on all JVMs - it's a good idea to always use `getBytes("UTF-8")` to ensure that encoding is consistent.

For example, use `getBytes("UTF-8")` and `getBytes("UTF-16")` and compare the results (the latter will likely have twice as many bytes as the former)

Comment: If a method returns a `byte[]`, how do I know its `CharSet`? Example: `public static byte[] sha(byte[] data)` http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha%28byte[]%29

Comment: @Kevin That sha() method operates on an array of bytes. CharSets are irrelevant when operating on byte arrays (until you convert them to a String).

Comment: According to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream), [this library](http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/) can help - it's not guaranteed to be able to detect the encoding, but it usually can.

Comment: @Kevin You specified the charset when you converted a String to a byte array. But let's back up... what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @dnault Compare these two: `byte[] stringBytes = someString.getBytes("UTF-8")` and the result of `byte[] bytes = sha1(someBytes)`. I'm getting separate values when I compare each particular byte, but I expect them to match. That's why I am curious if I'm using the right encoding for `someBytes`