# Why Shift_JIS charset encoded file return as EUC_JP type?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have an application which detects charset encoding, when I test an Shift_JIS file as input it returns a charset encoding type as EUC_JP.

I have used {"EUC_JP","Shift_JIS","UTF-8"} and passed to the following method as Charset instance one by one to check charset encoding.

## Below is my code for decoding

```
private Charset detectCharset(File file, Charset charset)
{
    try
    {
        BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
        decoder.reset();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        boolean identified = false;

        while ((input.read(buffer) != -1) && (!identified))
        {
            identified = identify(buffer, decoder);
        }
        input.close();

        if (!identified)
        {
            charset = null;
        }

        return charset;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

private boolean identify(byte[] bytes, CharsetDecoder decoder)
{
    boolean isIdentifies = true;
    try
    {
        decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
    }
    catch (CharacterCodingException e)
    {
        isIdentifies = false;
    }
    return isIdentifies;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your methodology for identifying character encodings is flawed, I think.  The `decode` method is only going to throw a `CharacterCodingException` if the buffer contents cannot be decoded at all.  It will not throw one in the case where the bytes can be decoded, but the result is jibberish.  It has no way of distinguishing meaningful and meaningless sequences of characters.

Here are some relevant references, giving better approaches:

- [Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream) - the Answers variously discuss the nature of the problem and suggest relevant libraries.
- http://tika.apache.org/0.8/api/org/apache/tika/parser/txt/CharsetDetector.html - another library ...

But you need to bear in mind that *any* algorithm for detecting character encodings can give the wrong answer on occasion.