# InputStreamReader not throwing UnsupportedEncodingException

Tags: java, character-encoding

If I pass in a UTF-16 encoded file to the following code then will I get an UnsupportedEncodingException?

```
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String ip;
        while ((ip = br.readLine()) != null){
            //do something
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException use) { 
        //when can I expect an exception?
    }
```

I have tried this with a UTF-16 file but I am not getting any exception. The reader somehow tries to read all the characters which causes it to read more line than expected. For example in a sample file with 3 lines the reader reads 5 lines, 2 of which are empty lines.

Comment: `UnsupportedEncodingException` would through exception if that encoding is not **supported** . `UTF-8`,`UTF-16` are both supported & valid encodings.

Comment: If you want to detect encoding _errors_ you cannot use the "standard" Java classes; you have to go through a `CharsetDecoder`. See also the `CodingErrorAction` class: the default for all classes is to `CodingErrorAction.REPLACE` and not `REPORT`

Comment: Note that curiously enough, _no class_ in the JDK apart from `CharsetDecoder` allows you to detect encoding errors... Not even a `Reader` class. If you want that you'd have to create your own `Reader` implementation! That kind of sucks.

Comment: thanks a lot guys and yes +1 for figuring out that I am looking for CharsetDecoder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UnsupportedEncodingException` is only thrown if the name of the charset you pass to the `Charset.forName()` is not supported. It does not relate to the content of the stream (the Exception is declared to be thrown by the `Charset.forName()` not by `BufferedReader` or `InputStreamReader` classes).

Comment: I can accept this in 10min. So, what should I do to find out if I have got the correctly encoded stream?

Comment: Detecting file content encoding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream