# How to read textfiles with unknown encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, java-io

I want to read several text files (eg CSV), but I don't know the encoding.

As the textfiles may contain special chars like umlauts, chosing the right encoding seems to be crucial.

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), encoding));
```

I tried reading with `ISO_8859_1` which did not work propertly with umlauts encoded. So I tried `UTF-8`, which works.

But I don't know in future if this might also cause problems with different files. And I never now before reading a file in which encoding the file is.

So how should I best read files with encoding unknown?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking the other two answers are right - you just have to *know* what the encoding is to be guaranteed of anything. However, there are libraries out there that will allow you to make educated guesses about the encoding. Check out [ICU4J](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection) or [jchardet](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/), for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the encoding, you cannot read the files correctly if you don't know it. As UTF-8 works just keep using it. Also check with the producer of the files if they will keep producing them in UTF-8. They should document this.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to programmatically recognize encoding of a text file. The only way is to try to open it in a text editor with different encodings until you can read the text