# getting a UTF-8 string out of a file

Tags: java, io

im trying to work on a folder full with downloaded xml (html)  files.
for now , the files are .txt files with hebrew in them , as i can see when i open the files.

when im trying to make a string out of the file to work on it , all of the hebrew becomes gibbrish.
any ideas?

```
String fileSource = ("path/path");
    File  folder= new File(fileSource);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (File currentFile : listOfFiles) {
        try {
            content = FileUtils.readFileToString(currentFile , "UTF-8");
```

if i go and save the files as UTF-8 , it works. but i have so many files like that to work with.

Comment: Try `FileUtils.readFileToString(currentFile , "ISO-8859-1");`

Comment: as in going to run configurations and setting it as an argument?
didnt work... any other suggestions?

Comment: instead of getting question marks , i get mainly 'x' and some other symbols.

Comment: Sorry, my codepage part was off; Part 8 (`ISO-8859-8`) has the Latin/Hebrew alphabet, as suggested by @Martin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that when you open a file, your browser/text-editor opens it as an `ISO-8859-8` encoded file. When you save as UTF-8, it is why your above code works.

Therefore, your code need to open the file the same way as your browser/text-editor.

Try

```
FileUtils.readFileToString(currentFile , "ISO-8859-8");
```

EDIT:

Since we don't know the encoding your file uses, we can also try Windows 1255:

```
FileUtils.readFileToString(currentFile , Charset.forName("cp1255"));
```

Which appears to be the [most common encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255) for Hebrew according to Wikipedia.

> Windows-1255 Hebrew is always in logical order (as opposed to visual). Microsoft Hebrew products (Windows, Office and Internet Explorer) brought logically-ordered Hebrew to common use, with the result that Windows-1255 is the Hebrew encoding that can be found most on the Web, having ousted the visually ordered ISO-8859-8, and preferred to the logically ordered ISO-8859-8-I because it provides for vowel-points.

Comment: Perhaps it is `UTF-16` then. Try that in your original code. If that doesn't work either, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4735911/276949. It will heuristically detect the encoding you are using.

Comment: @BarHoshen, what do you do with `content` after you've read the file? Are you sure that your post-processing is using the correct charset -- and what is the default charset of your JVM?

Comment: UTF-8 is the charset. 
and even when i just syso it , its not good.
i need to run on it and extract some info.

btw - solved it with help of a friend by VB code that makes every file on a folder into UTF-8..
still i belive something is wrong in my work here and trying to figure it out

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that after you re-save the file as UTF-8 it begins working. To me that implies that the original file is not actually UTF-8. If you post the before/after files somewhere, I can take a quick look.