# csv character set load infile issue

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jdbc, utf-8

i have a MySQL database having standard encoding and server encoding all set as utf8.I have csv files coming in of multiple encoding which I have to load in the database using jdbc. But when the incoming file is of encoding ANSII, load data infile fails

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid utf8 character string: '1080'
```

I am creating a table `table_abc` based on csv headers and then using the below query to load the csv file into database

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'XXX.csv' INTO TABLE table_abc CHARACTER SET UTF8  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Here is my DB definition

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\charsets\
```

What should I do now,

1. Should i convert all files to utf8 before uploading? if yes then how in Java
2. Should I have multiple encoded tables for multiple encoded files? If yes, then how do i detect encoding of incoming file in java?

P.S I have no issues in missing out non-utf8 characters while loading in the table, my only intention is the sucessful upload of the file in the DB without giving any error irrespective of encoding.

Thanks

Comment: Without seeing the code that reads the file, the JDBC code, and a definition of your database table, it is difficult to understand your problem.  Are you uploading the entire CSV file as a single text value?  A binary blob?

Comment: I have edited the question, Please look at it. :)

Comment: Are you asking whether the best practice would be to change the encoding of the file, or change the `CHARACTER SET` portion of your SQL?

Comment: Yes..If I can change the encoding of the csv file, That would serve the purpose.But I dont know the present encoding of the file beforehand

Comment: The source of each file (person or program) knows what its encoding is;  that is pretty much the only way to know a file’s encoding.  You cannot auto-detect a file’s charset, unless it starts with a byte order mark character (which most don’t);  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream .

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that some columns are utf8 and some columns are, say, latin1, then it gets a bit complicated, but still possible.

Create a "staging" table to put the data into from the `LOAD`.  But have all the `VARCHAR` columns be `VARBINARY` and `TEXT` be `BLOB`.  This way the data bytes will be loaded unchanged.

Then `ALTER` that table to convert the binary/blob columns to the suitable varchar/text types:

```
ALTER ...
    MODIFY COLUMN col1 VARCHAR(111) CHARACTER SET ... COLLATION ...,
    MODIFY COLUMN col2 TEXT CHARACTER SET ... COLLATION ...,
    ...;
```

Then copy the data over to your 'real' table (unless this table is sufficient).

If one *column* has a mixture of encodings, you are SOOL.

**Identifying a charset**

Provide a sample or two of the HEX of non-English characters in the column; I can usually spot what it is.  [*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#diagnosing_charset_issues) gives some clues of how to recognize a charset from hex samples.

Comment: Okay...But how do i know the character set of the column to convert to...I mean character set of the data in a column?

Comment: I added a link to identification techniques.