# JAVA Code To Identify A String With UTF-8 data

Tags: java, utf-8, 8-bit

I am trying to standardize a set of data.  Some of the names were UTF-8 encoded, others were not.  What I need to do in JAVA is detect if the name was UTF encoded or not using some form of conditional logic so I can translate each row correctly.

```
String s1 = "JosÃ© Flores";
String s1 = "José Flores";

IF [condition] (identify UTF-8)
    byte[] utf8Bytes = s1.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    String s2 = new String(utf8Bytes,"UTF-8");
ELSE
    String s2 = s1;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [juniversalchardet](https://code.google.com/archive/p/juniversalchardet/) , you can get the encoding , then do the condition operation. This could help you get encoding type.

```
public static String guessEncoding(byte[] bytes) {
String DEFAULT_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector detector =
    new org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector(null);
detector.handleData(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
detector.dataEnd();
String encoding = detector.getDetectedCharset();
detector.reset();
if (encoding == null) {
    encoding = DEFAULT_ENCODING;
  }
 return encoding;
}
```

This require juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar, Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream) are some info