# Determine file encoding and print umlaute

Tags: java, encoding

I have a txt file. I'm not sure of the encoding of this file. Probably it's s EBCDIC. I have problem with Umlaute (äöü, ÜÄÖ) 
e.g.
For example:
Displayed: Mnchen
should be: München
Url to test file: http://wyslijto.pl/plik/yiewa11y3p

```
java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream("/Downloads/test.txt")));

//        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
//                new InputStreamReader(
//                        new FileInputStream("/Downloads/test.txt"), Charset.forName("windows-1252")));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use a proper encoding and set the buffereader with UTF8

Comment: Basically, you need to find out the encoding. I doubt that it's EBCDIC, or it would be considerably more broken than it is now. I suggest you find out more about what produced the file, and use that information to try to find out the encoding.

Comment: `file` says: "Downloads/test.txt: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with no line terminators", so @vs97 's answer should work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no certain way to detect encoding without knowing what was used to create the file in the first place. I will refer you to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream), it has a lot of suggestions how one could make an *intelligent guess* what the encoding really is.

Once you know the encoding (that's the difficult part), its simple. For example, if the encoding was to be UTF-8, use UTF-8 charset with your [InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream("/Downloads/test.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

In general, the supported Charsets are:

- ISO_8859_1
- US_ASCII
- UTF_16
- UTF_16BE
- UTF_16LE
- UTF_8

Comment: That will only help if it actually *is* UTF-8. The OP says they don't know what the encoding is.

Comment: (And `Files.newBufferedReader` would be a simpler way of doing the above, as that uses UTF-8 by default.)

Comment: The problem it is that the character is UTF-8. Probably double encoded, so it require two decoding.