# Scala - Detecting a files character encoding

Tags: scala, file, character-encoding

I want to be able to detect the character encoding of a file without knowing about the file's metadata. Is there a way to do this without looping through every row of a file and looking for characters of a specific encoding?

Comment: You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream

Comment: Even Google can't do it for each case, even with looping through every row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream)

Comment: You mean you want to guess, based on the current content of the file, right?

Comment: Not guess because it has to be accurate. I don't think what I've asked is possible.

Comment: That is correct. Communicating text means both bytes and character encoding. Often the character encoding is implied or communication on a side channel like HTTP response header Content-Type. But, it is almost never stored with text files (though it could be in some file systems). That said, a text file with the bytes of a Unicode BOM, have a very high probability of being one of the easily distinguished Unicode encodings.