# How can i create and detect a file with a specific encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

i try to create a file with a specific encoding:

```
File fi_export = new File(file_export_name);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fi_export);
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
                        
writer.println("A");
writer.close();
os.close();
                        
String charsetTest = getCharset(fi_export);
log.println("> CHARSET TEST "+charsetTest);
```

My getCharset function looks like:

```
private String getCharset(File file) {
        String charset = "";
        try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            CharsetDetector cd = new CharsetDetector();
            cd.setText(bis);
            CharsetMatch cm = cd.detect();
            if (cm != null) {
               Reader reader = cm.getReader();
               charset = cm.getName();
            }
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return charset;
    }
```

And this is my log output:

```
> CHARSET TEST UTF-8
```

I specified the OutputStreamWriter with the encoding: ISO_8859_1. But the file was not created in 8859_1. It was detected as UTF-8.

Why? I did not find any solution. I am sitting here since 5 hours. Maybe you can help?

Comment: This is not possible to do exactly in general, because multiple character sets use the same bytes to encode the same characters. For example `A` has the value 65 in ASCII, UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 and other character sets. So if you find the value 65 in a file, the original character set that was used could be any of those.

Comment: Yeah, there really is no reliable way to detect a charset, unless it’s UTF-16, or UTF-8 text containing non-ASCII characters.  There is far too much ambiguity.  The same byte values can be used in many charsets.

Comment: You should add the _library_ you're using to your question's _tags_.

Comment: Auto-detection won't be reliable, see also : [Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream)

Comment: The information technology industry has never been able to define a standard for file meta-data such as indicating the character encoding. Other than the presence of a [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), guessing (heuristics)  is the only way. See [*Charset detection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charset_detection) in Wikipedia.