# Greek String doesn't match regex when read from keyboard

Tags: java, regex

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   String str1 = "ΔΞ123456";
   System.out.println(str1+"-"+str1.matches("^\\p{InGreek}{2}\\d{6}")); //ΔΞ123456-true

   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   String str2 = br.readLine(); //ΔΞ123456 same as str1.
   System.out.println(str2+"-"+str2.matches("^\\p{InGreek}{2}\\d{6}")); //Ξ”Ξ�123456-false

   System.out.println(str1.equals(str2)); //false
}
```

The same String doesn't match regex when read from keyboard.
What causes this problem, and how can we solve this?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  I used System.console() for input and output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter pr = System.console().writer();

        String str1 = "ΔΞ123456";
        pr.println(str1+"-"+str1.matches("^\\p{InGreek}{2}\\d{6}")+"-"+str1.length());

        String str2 = System.console().readLine();
        pr.println(str2+"-"+str2.matches("^\\p{InGreek}{2}\\d{6}")+"-"+str2.length());

        pr.println("str1.equals(str2)="+str1.equals(str2));
}
```

Output:

> ΔΞ123456-true-8
>   ΔΞ123456
>   ΔΞ123456-true-8
>   str1.equals(str2)=true

Comment: How do you know that str2 is the same as str1? What method did you use to verify that they are in fact the same?

Comment: You are right Mark. Its not the same as i thought.

Comment: Print out all java properties: System.getProperties().list(System.out);
Look for "file.encoding".

Comment: Be aware that there are code points within the Greek block that are not in the Greek script, and similarly there are *many* code points which **are** in the Greek script but which **are not** in Greek block. The [unichars program](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars) run as `unichars -u '\p{InGreek}' '\P{IsGreek}' | wc -l` shows there are 28 of the first group, while `unichars -a '\p{IsGreek}' '\P{InGreek}' | wc -l` shows there are 395 in the second group. See also the [uniprops program](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniprops) for exploring things the other way around.

Comment: I should probably add that **Java doesn’t support Unicode script types until JDK7!** You can kinda use `[\p{InGreek}\p{InGreekExtended}\p{InAncientGreekNumbers}\p{InAncientGreekMusicalNotation}]`, but there are still 66 code points in those four blocks that are **not** of type `Script=Greek`.

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?  +1 for JDK version !

Comment: Did you both compile with `javac ‑encoding UTF‑8` and also run with `java ‑Dfile.encoding=UTF‑8`?

Comment: @Stefanos: @Whom are you addressing with the IDE question?

Comment: @tchrist: I am not familiar with those terms(script,block), but it was good that you pointed out this detail. I tried javac ‑encoding UTF‑8 and java ‑Dfile.encoding=UTF‑8 didn't work.

Comment: @Stefanos: I am using the latest Eclipse(3.6.1) if you are asking me. And jdk1.6.0_23

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use Windows, it may be caused by the fact that console character encoding ("OEM code page") is not the same as a system encoding ("ANSI code page").

`InputStreamReader` without explicit encoding parameter assumes input data to be in the system default encoding, therefore characters read from the console are decoded incorrectly.

In order to correctly read non-us-ascii characters in Windows console you need to specify console encoding explicitly when constructing `InputStreamReader` (required codepage number can be found by executing `mode con cp` in the command line):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(System.in, "CP737"));
```

The same problem applies to the output, you need to construct `PrintWriter` with proper encoding:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWrtier(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "CP737"));
```

---

**Note** that since Java 1.6 you can avoid these workarounds by using [`Console`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) object obtained from `System.console()`. It provides `Reader` and `Writer` with correctly configured encoding as well as some utility methods.

However, `System.console()` returns `null` when streams are redirected (for example, when running from IDE). A workaround for this problem can be found in McDowell's answer.

**See also:**

- [Code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)

Comment: I tried BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8")); but didn't work. I also tried CP1253.

Comment: @athspk: You need OEM codepage of Greek Windows. It should be `CP737` or `CP869`, I'm not sure which one.

Comment: @athspk: What's the result of `str2.length()`?

Comment: @athspk: The output clearly says you have UTF-8 input interpreted as Windows-1252. Are you sure `new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"))` doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't work, neither from the IDE, nor by running from command line. When i run from command line, str2 is ??123456, and the length is now 8 (same as str1)

Comment: @athspk: You can try reading input via `System.console()`, as suggested by McDowell. Also, what does `mode con cp` command show?

Comment: mode con cp = 737. I tried new InputStreamReader(System.in, "737") before but didn't work WHEN RUNNING FROM IDE. Now i ran it from command line and the regexp matched! Output: ─╬123456-true. How do i get the string to print correctly?

Comment: @athspk: For output you need to create `PrintWriter` with proper encoding, the same way you do for input. Since Java 1.6 you also can avoid all these problems by using `System.console()` for input and output.

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple places where transcoding errors can take place here.

1. Ensure that your class is being compiled correctly (unlikely to be an issue in an IDE):

   - Ensure that the compiler is using the same encoding as your editor (i.e. if you save as UTF-8, [set your compiler to use that encoding](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options))
   - Or switch to escaping to the ASCII subset that most encodings are a superset of (i.e. change the string literal to `"\u0394\u039e123456"`)
2. Ensure you are reading input using the correct encoding:

   - Use the [Console](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29) to read input - this class will detect the console encoding
   - Or configure your Reader to use the [correct encoding](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html#charsets_1252) (probably windows-1253) or set the console to Java's [default encoding](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29)

*Note that `System.console()` returns null in an IDE, but there are [things you can do about that](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html).*

Answer (score 1):

I get true in both cases with nothing changed on your code. (I tested with greek layout keyboard - I'm from Greece :])
Probably your keyboard is sending ascii in 8859-7 ISO and not UTF-8. Mine sends UTF-8.

EDIT: I still get true with the addition of the equals command..

```
System.out.println(str1.equals(str2));
```

Check if you can get it working by changing everything to greek in the regional options (if you are using windows).

```
Rundll32 Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL Intl.cpl,,0
```

If this is the case then you can act accordingly.. as 'axtavt' said

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard is likely not sending the characters as UTF-8, but as the operating system's default character encoding.

#### See also

- [Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream)
- [Java App : Unable to read iso-8859-1 encoded file correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498636/java-app-unable-to-read-iso-8859-1-encoded-file-correctly)